# What exactly does civil law mean?

Tags: terminology, old-testament, mosaic-law, tripartite-law-division

The laws in the Old Testament can be separated into 3 categories as useful guides:

1. Moral laws.
2. Ceremonial laws.
3. Civil laws.

Moral laws deal with right and wrong behaviour, in relations to the relationships an individual has with their neighbours and God.

Ceremonial laws deal with how one is to conduct themselves before God's presence, including the need to be pure etc. This may be controversial to Christians but I don't think ceremonial laws are just laws that pertain to Jews. That's because in the bigger picture, ceremonial laws teach OT believers, regardless of ethnicity, about the nature of sacrifice and atonement according to Hebrews 10:3, which foreshadow Jesus's ultimate atoning sacrifice for humanity. Additionally, it also teaches humanity the fundamental concept that God only accepts and dwells with those who are sinless. In short, its like a special treat for believers, after accepting God as their Saviour, since it tells the mechanisms by which God accepts and forgives them. That's also probably why God rarely (or never) condemned those completely distanced from Israelite culture based on their violation of the ceremonial laws. They've already rejected God, which in turn is rejection of His provisions to forgive. It'd be superfluous and God is always pesky about judging fairly and impartially.

So what are civil laws? I constantly hear conflicting opinions such as how [civil laws are really just penalties for moral law violations etc.](https://jdgreear.com/blog/why-dont-we-follow-all-of-the-old-testament-laws/) If so, why make the distinction? And according to Google, civil means anything that's not related to military or ecclesiastic affairs. Do these laws refer to the ones that specifically enable Israel to function properly as a nation, which in turn showcase God's pragmatic wisdom? Laws related to infrastructure such as estbalishing borders in the Promised Land, slave-based economy, monarchy, quarantine etc.??

There's plenty of laws like this in the Old Testament and I don't necessarily see how it relates to morality or even worshipping God (but of course, He places regulations so that the infrastructure can benefit the community). And unlike the moral and ceremonial law, these laws aren't necessarily universal and can be dropped depending on Israel's environment/situation. Eg in the Book of Ezra and Nehemiah, God never once condemned the Israelites for not restoring the monarchy once they returned from exile to re-establish their nation. Should there be a better and less misleading term for such laws?

FYI: Jesus fulfilled the civil laws, as part of His mission to fulfill the entire 613 commandments, by perfectly encapsulating the underlying wisdom of these laws (1 Corinthians 1:30). This underlying pragmatic wisdom is also useful for the NT Israel (aka the Church) to adopt, especially since they are in this world, although they're not part of it.

*Some of you may think that because these "pragmatic" OT civil laws could be used (and dropped) at any circumstance, does this mean that we should adopt some of them in today's politics so that governments can be more "biblical"? Whilst some of these laws may fit for today's world, such as the quarantine and hygiene laws in Exodus, they do not always fit. A slave-based economy, for example, would be very impractical for today's world. Even in the quarantine and hygiene laws, they do not account for all diseases. So the best way to make politics more "biblical"? Rely on wisdom. Enforce a universal morality. Punish those who wish to destroy/ruin society.*

Comment: The whole scheme is deeply problematic, but yes it's usually seen as a catch-all for the things which aren't "moral" (even though they all are) or ceremonial. Things like how many horses the king can have, building balconies, property disputes, or returning your neighbour's lost sheep.

Comment: Like I said, its only a useful construct for us to understand these complex OT laws. There's evidently a difference between a law that prohibits you from murdering and laws that command you to build a centralised Temple for example.

Comment: cf. St. Thomas Aquinas's [Treatise on Law, _Summa Theologica_ I-II qq. 90-180](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/FS.html#TOC09), esp.  [q. 91. Of the Various Kinds of Law](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/FS/FS091.html#FSQ91OUTP1) (eternal, natural, human, and divine law) and q[q. 98](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/FS/FS098.html#FSQ98OUTP1)ff. on the Old Law and its types (moral, ceremonial, judicial precepts).